# Log forwarding in partially disconnected client

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Considering the following architecture:

I have a laptop connected to a server over ethernet.
This laptop is configured to send log events with rsyslog on the server, the server is configured to accept those logs and store them in a file that can be used later with log exploitation software.

The problem is, the laptop can sometimes be disconnected to work on a remote location then can be plugged on several hours later. But I still want to transfer all the local event to the server after reconnection.

My idea at the moment is using the `omrelp` module for syslog and store the events locally in a disk queue, but I'm not so sure about the behaviour when the syslog server will be available again. Is there a timeout/limit after when the relp protocol will not resend the message? Or maybe it is just not appropriate for my case.

The other solution is creating custom scripts to reconciliate logs between client and server after the reconnection but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: There are solutions, but they go in to the enterprise segment. Are you ready for this?

Comment: I have full control over the environment so if there is an acceptable solution I can take a look at it, can you explain a little more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsyslog provides a queueing mechanism for all actions. The queue stays in
memory until too large, or on shutdown, when it moves to disk. You can use
it with the normal tcp `omfwd` forwarding setup, without resorting to
`omrelp`.

Read more about
[queues](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/queues.html), and
see the full
[queue options](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rainerscript/queue_parameters.html)
documentation, or look at the second RedHat
[example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-using_the_new_syntax_for_rsyslog_queues)
*"25.14. Forwarding To a Single Server Using the New Syntax"*.

If you had legacy syntax like

```
*.* @@192.168.0.2:514
```

or the RainerScript version

```
action(type="omfwd" Target="192.168.0.2" Port="514" Protocol="tcp")
```

replace it with something like

```
action(type="omfwd" Target="192.168.0.2" Port="514" Protocol="tcp"
       queue.type="linkedlist"
       queue.filename="stufftoforward"
       action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
       queue.saveOnShutdown="on")
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I have in mind is to use Splunk. You install on client(s) (laptop) Universal Forwarder, configure it to watch the logs, install on server Splunk server (indexer and search head), configure it and wait for data. If you are not connected client wait and when "see" the server it start forwarding the logs. Later you can do extensive analyses on the logs via graphic interface.

This solution can applied also on other machines (clients)

The negative points are:

1. You have 500MB of logs per day, for more traffic you should buy license
2. I am not sure how good Splunk handle logrotation. AFAIK if rotation happen during offline you may not get the logs from rotated file (/var/log/messages1 for example). Here is one [answer](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Knowledge-Management/About-log-rotation-best-practices/m-p/347457) about this subject.

Comment: Isn't this like *using a sledgehammer to crack a nut*?

Comment: @eDonkey, depend of many details :)